# Confusion with signed and unsigned int

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem from [here](https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1646/) using a [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree). My code is as follows:

```
class BIT {
public:
    BIT(std::vector<int> list) {
        m_array = std::vector<int>(list.size() + 1, 0);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < list.size(); idx++) {
            update(idx, list[idx]);
        }
    }


    int prefix_query(int idx) const {
        int result = 0;
        for (++idx; idx > 0; idx -= idx & -idx) {
            result += m_array[idx];
        }
        return result;
    }

    int range_query(int from_idx, int to_idx) const {
        // Computes the range sum between two indices (both inclusive)
        if (from_idx == 0)
            return prefix_query(to_idx);
        else
            return prefix_query(to_idx) - prefix_query(from_idx - 1);
    }

    void update(int idx, int add) {
        // Add a value to the element at index idx
        for (++idx; idx < m_array.size(); idx += idx & -idx) {
            m_array[idx] += add;
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> m_array;
};

int main () {
    int n, q, a, b, c;
    std::cin >> n >> q;
    std::vector<int> vec(n+1);
    for(int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++){
        std::cin >> a;
        vec.push_back(a);
    }
    BIT bit(vec);
    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        std::cin >> b >> c;
        std::cout << bit.range_query(b, c) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

I get these compiler warnings from the online judge 
[image]

I tried casting idx into a signed number using `(signed) idx` but when I do that the code returns 0 for what ever value I enter. I can't understand what's wrong because it runs fine on my machine as it is but the C++ complier in the online judge is not very helpful in suggesting anything useful.

Comment: `int`, `signed int`, and `signed` are all the same type. `(signed)idx` is a no-op.

Comment: What compiler are you using locally?

Comment: Why not just use the auto keyword?

Comment: `.size()` returns an unsigned value. You need to make `idx` an unsigned variable to match.

Comment: Just change `idx` to `unsigned`.

Comment: @Rietty it still returns 0 for all the answers when I use auto.

Comment: @MarkRansom no more issues with the compiler but now all it does is return 0 when I do that.

Comment: @user207421 I did and now it returns 0 instead of the results from the test cases shown below.

Comment: The warning appears in the constructor and the update method, and neither of those returns anything.

Comment: Changing to unsigned seems strange for `idx += idx & -idx`.  What does this do?

Comment: @stark it updates the value at the i-th index of array by adding the value add to the required index.

Comment: No it doesn't, it updates a whole lot of elements as given by that expression, which comes from the Fenwick tree definition.

Comment: Of course you need to *not* change it other than in the constructor and the update method, because in the others you're comparing as `> 0`, and unsigned numbers are never negative.

Comment: The update method is where it is using `-idx`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for not reading all the code carefully. Keep `idx` signed, and cast `.size()` to signed as well. That will only fail if `size` returns something impractically big.

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector::size` is usually of type `size_t`, which is unsigned.
So casting or declaring idx as an unsigned type should fix the compiler warnings.